# VBA Multi Criteria Search in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of about 500K items in a table. I need to match based on year and service code.
I am trying to make it dynamic because i need to search through tons of sheets and rows. So basically i have this:

'I would rather not do this but i can't figure it out. This creates a temporary range for each 'variable. I do this because when i enter the below formula in a cell with ranges it works.

```
Sheets("Worker").Range("A1").Name = "yearlk"
Sheets("Worker").Range("A2").Name = "svclk"

For xlRow = 2 To xlLastRow

    Range("yearlk").Value = Cells(xlRow, xlColYear) 'Sets the range to the current year
    Range("svclk").Value = Cells(xlRow, xlServiceCode) 'sets the range to current ServiceCode

    Exists = Evaluate("{=INDEX(vwSVC_RegTool[service_code_id],MATCH(1,(vwSVC_RegTool[term_year]=yearlk)*(vwSVC_RegTool[service_code_id]=svclk),0))}")

next xlRow
```

What is annoying me is, it all works in cells, but i am making a custom tool so it needs to work from an xlam.

Comment: Now if i am going about this all wrong OK ... my main goal is to say ... Year = 2012 and SVC = A52453 ... does that combo exist in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to answer the question above, however, I simply set the range to a variant, then setup another variable to be the index and did 2 loops, it was WAY WAY WAY fast.

```
SVCtran = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CPT Codes and HCPCS").Range("vwSVC_RegTool")
ReDim SVCStor(UBound(SVCtran))
For I = 1 To UBound(SVCtran)
    SVCStor(I) = SVCtran(I, 1)
Next

II = Int(Sqr(UBound(SVCStor))) 'this setups the index size
ReDim SVCIndex(II, 2)
For I = 1 To UBound(SVCIndex) - 1
    SVCIndex(I, 1) = II * I 'set position of index
    SVCIndex(I, 2) = SVCStor(II * I) 'set value of index Start
Next I
SVCIndex(UBound(SVCIndex), 1) = UBound(SVCStor)
```

then the index in actionFor xlRow = 1 To xlLastRow - 1
    For xlRow to xlLastRow
        Exists = True
        compare = ColValue2(xlRow, 1) & ColValue(xlRow, 1)

```
    For R = 1 To UBound(SVCIndex) 'find the start and finish of the index
        If SVCIndex(R, 2) > compare And compare >= SVCIndex(R - 1, 2) Then
            Start = SVCIndex(R - 1, 1)
            Ender = SVCIndex(R, 1)
        End If
    Next

    For R = Start To Ender 'set the loop to only look in the index locations
        Exists = False
        If compare = SVCStor(R) Then
            Exists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Exists = False Then
        InvalidFormat(I) = xlRow '2014Z0334
        I = I + 1
    End If

Next
```

The idea is this originally had about 1.6MM records to search searching about 100K times. I know real mathematician will kill what i am about to say but that is about avg 80 Billion searches. With this we get 1.6M set into 1264 index of size 1265 giving an avg search of 126MM .... insanity****note this MUST MUST MUST be an ordered list